# android app installs but won't open on android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, leanback

I have built an app using the leanback library leanback version 17:23.1.1.

Here is the story so far:

1) the app runs on all my android devices with 5.0 or higher.
2) the app runs in the emulator with Android 5.0 or higher AND android 4.4 as the OS

The issue is that it will not open and run on my two devices that are an android tv box with kitkat (Android 4.4.2). I can install the app and see it in the installed apps list; but I cannot OPEN the app, nor will it run on the device

I used android studio to create the app. Here is the app gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx'
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'


}
```

How can I get the app to run on my android 4.4 device??

Comment: Please explain **precisely** what you mean by "I cannot OPEN/RUN the app".

Comment: Have you looked at the logcat when you try to open the app? Maybe it crashes before it even opens.

Comment: Yes I did and there is no indication of a crash. It works on the emulator and both android 5.0 tablets I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to an Android 5.1 device and all is well. Also I installed the Android leanback launcher on the 5.1 and 4.4 device and it worked as well on both.

Adjusting the API levels for minimum and target in the Androidmenfext.xml file worked as well.

Thanks

ironmantis7x